# NUnit и unit-тестирование вообще: есть ли вводные статьи?

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, nunit, xunit

я пытаюсь понять юнит-тестирование. я столкнулся с проблемой:

есть множество статей (например, [вот эта](https://habr.com/ru/post/181255/)), которые написаны в стиле "берем и делам то то и то то. Видите, как клёво получилось?" - абсолютно без объяснения, ЗАЧЕМ мы делаем то или иное действие.

По сути, юнит-тесты - это явно не рокет-сайенс. Их суть, как я понимаю, в том, что мы создаём по экземпляру тестируемого класса, и пытаемся у него вызывать разные методы.

Но кроме очевидных тестов (типа проверки того, что при определенных аргументах функция вернет такой то результат) сложности добавляет использование моков.

На эту тему я не нашел никакой связаной информации на русском, но нашел два видеокурса на английском:

Mocking with Moq and NUnit

и аналогичную

Mocking with Moq and xUnit

Не посоветуете ли Вы мне какую то вводную статью, которая может объяснить методику, а не то, какие кнопки надо нажимать в определенной IDE, чтобы составить, написать и запустить тесты?

Спасибо.

Comment: Советую книгу Growing Object Oriented Software Guided by Tests. Там примеры на java, но эта книга очень хороша, пожалуй лучшее, что есть про тестирование.

Comment: Еще рекомендую https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservice-testing/ Не смотрите, что там микросервисы, там хорошо описан контекст, назначение и виды тестов, и также некотороые инструменты.

Comment: @RomanKonoval - большое спасибо за совет! Книгу уже нашел, жалею только, что там наверняка "не те моки" описаны, что сейчас используются

Comment: Почему не те? Библиотека может быть и не та (там используется jMock, я его давно ни использовал и не знаю, как он сейчас по сравнению с mockito, опять же это из мира java), но принцип, а ведь вы его хотите понять, тот же и он не изменился и применим к любой реализации.

Comment: Есть же классическая книга от Роя Ошерова https://www.manning.com/books/the-art-of-unit-testing - там даже с примерами для дотнета (ищите самую свежую версию)

Comment: и суть юнит тестов не в создании классов или вызова чего то, а в том, чтобы программист спал спокойно :)